# When I Replace Remote File with Local File Console Error - Skulpt

Tags: javascript, html, skulpt

I am making a Python editor in HTML and JavaScript, with CodeMirror for code indentation, line numbering and syntax coloring, and Skulpt for the execution.

I have some code that had an external script referenced in it (`http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="codemirror.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="python.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var editor;
        function outf(text) {
            var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
            mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
        }

        function builtinRead(x) {
            if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
                throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
            return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
        }

        function runit() {
                var prog = editor.getDoc().getValue();
                var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
                mypre.innerHTML = '';
                Sk.pre = "dynamicframe";
                Sk.configure({
                    output: outf,
                    read: builtinRead
                });
                (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'canvas';
                var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
                    return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
                });
                myPromise.then(function(mod) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        console.log(err.toString());
                    });
            }
            //<![CDATA[
        window.onload = function() {
                editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('textbox'), {
                    mode: {
                        name: "python",
                        version: 2,
                        singleLineStringErrors: false
                    },
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    indentUnit: 4
                });
            } //]]>
    </script>
    <textarea id="textbox" name="textbox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="runit()" type="button">Run</button>
    <pre id="dynamicframe"></pre>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want all the scripts stored locally (excluding jQuery), so I copied over `http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js` to the local server and called it `skulpt.min.js`. I then changed the line:

```
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

to...

```
<script src="skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

and now the code is bringing up this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sk is not defined
```

on line 38 of the HTML:

```
Sk.pre = "dynamicframe";
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is `skulpt.min.js` in the same directory as your HTML file?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error? If so, it means it can't find the file. If not, make sure you saved the file. `skulpt.min.js` might be empty or incorrect.

Comment: nope no 404 here, and the contents of the file is displayed

Comment: Displayed how? Seeing them in your text editor or whatever doesn't mean it's saved. Here's the thing: if you have the file and it's locating the file, then that means the contents of the file must be wrong. There's no other explanation unless you're doing something weird on the backend to replace the contents of a request for that particular file.

Comment: @MikeC When I go to the local file url in my web browser